# Fastest way to get Power by 2

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, performance, math

The question is simple; I need the fastest way to calculate power 2. I need that for this formula which calculates distance between 2 points.

```
var Dist:int = Math.sqrt(  (mmx - ox) * (mmx - ox)  +  (mmy - oy) * (mmy - oy)  );
```

Any idea?

Comment: the time for the sqrt call will far outweigh the multiplication

Comment: http://www.boostworthy.com/blog/?p=197

Comment: Squaring is not done with bit-shift. You're thinking of 2^n, not n^2. Also, why don't you use Math.pow?

Comment: simple multiplication is faster than using Math.Pow to square (usually). Not sure if the optimizer is able to intervene for an integral power of 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to calc sqrt for positive number `a`, take a recursive sequense

```
x_0 = a
x_n+1 = 1/2 * (x_n + a / x_n)
```

`x_n` goes to `sqrt(a)` with `n -> infinity`. first several iterations should be fast enough.

Hope that helps!

Comment: .. ummm .. I need a fast way for getting n * n and Math.pow is slow .. any suggestion?

Comment: @KataxEmperorKatax,I thought you want to spead-up `sqrt` calculation, it's much more slower then `n*n`.

Comment: How is _manually_ doing what `Math.sqrt` does under the covers give you _more_ speed exactly? You're taking the operation away from a blindingly fast CPU to a relatively glacial ActionScript.

Comment: @paxdiablo, is it a reason to put -1?!

Comment: Well, yes, because it's certainly not useful if it's _slower_ when the question asked for a _faster_ way :-) I'll be happy to reverse that if you can show me it's actually faster.

Comment: I thought that the trouble was with sqrt. As for speed. First iterations of the above sequence should be fast. So if you don't need high accuracy doing several iterations will be faster then `Math.sqrt`.

Answer (score 6):

The *fastest* way is often a lookup table, provided you can limit your input values to a small enough range, such as with (pseudo-code):

```
int sqr_arr[] = {0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, ...}
def sqr(n):
    if n < 0:
        return sqr(-n)
    if n >= len(sqr_arr):
        return n * n
    return sqr_arr[n]
```

This allows a high speed table lookup for lower values but reverts to the (probably) slower method if you try to use an argument not in your table.

But, as Mitch Wheat stated in a comment, speeding up the multiplication will not have much of an effect when the real bottleneck is the square root.

And remember: *measure, don't guess!* I consider myself reasonably adept at optimisation strategies but you should treat all advice (including mine) with the same circumspection as you would an alcoholic in the gutter, telling you how to live a long and successful life.

Comment: @paxdiablo, table lookup in as3 is slow, fastest way is todo the multiplication, and you are doing 2 branch test (n<0) and (n>len(...)) that is also slowing done your function.

Comment: @Patrick, that's fine. It was more general advice than AS-specific. As I said, you should _measure_ the performance of any purported improvements and, if they don't cut it, either improve them or throw them away.

Comment: @Katax: for a start, `pow` is totally unnecessary for `n*n`, just calculate `n * n`. The `pow` function might be better for higher powers but a simple square is probably best done with simple multiplication. If _that_ isn't fast enough, then you can try the lookup option I gave in this answer. It _may_ be faster, it may not. But you won't know till you try.

Comment: @paxdiablo ... thanks for your answer .. : ) ,, yes I think n*n is faster for my code because n is mouseX or mouseY and define an array for 1 to 1920 is heavy.